# A system of simultaneous quadratic 2 equations has a solution Iff each one has a solution.

Tags: linear-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

Could anyone tell me the name of the theorem that states that " A system of quadratic simultaneous 2 equations has a solution Iff each one has a solution "? And how can I prove it ?

Comment: When you say "quadratic simultaneous equations", how many variables are present? Can you maybe give an example?

Comment: Both of $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $x^2 + y^2 = 2$ have solutions, but together as a simultaneous system they have none.

Comment: 3 variables @Adrian Keister for example the system of simultaneous equations $ x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $x^2 - y^2 = w^2$. I want to show that it admits no solution in positive integers $ x, y, z, w$ .... may be by Fermat last theorem.

Comment: 3 variables @Arthur for example the system of simultaneous equations $ x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ and $x^2 - y^2 = w^2$. I want to show that it admits no solution in positive integers $ x, y, z, w$ .... may be by Fermat last theorem.